# Actor model advantages over task-based asynchronous pattern

Tags: c#, async-await, akka.net, actor-model

The actor model is known as a way to achieve better usage of CPU resources. In the same way, programming using C#'s async / await also help programmers to use threads properly since the thread is not blocked while making some IO call and then can be used to process another request.

Despite features like location transparency and fault tolerance, what are the advantages of using the actor model that Akka.NET implements over the task-based asynchronous pattern that is implemented in the .NET environment?

Answer (score 4):

> The actor model is known as a way to achieve better usage of CPU resources.

I've never thought of it that way. To me, the benefits of the actor model are in breaking the code into small actions that are easily understood, and connecting them with messages. It's the impact on design that is the real benefit.

> what are the advantages of using the actor model that Akka.NET implements over the task-based asynchronous pattern that is implemented in the .NET environment?

The two are orthogonal, so it doesn't make sense to compare them.

In particular, Akka.NET has support for working with `async`. You have the option of using `await` directly, in which case the message processing isn't considered complete until your `async` receive is done; or you can pipe the result of the task to yourself, in which case the message processing is considered done and a *new* message arrives with the result of that asynchronous operation.